# Jquery remove() not refreshing list of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm displaying a gallery of thumbnail images and when I select the remove button in the thumbnail I can remove the thumbnail from the gallery, but it doesn't refresh, leaving a blank space where the thumbnail was located. I tried, .sort() with no luck. Any help will be appreciated!

```js
$('.close').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  $("#sortable").sort();
});
```

```html
<div id="sortable">
  @foreach (var image in Model.Images) { 
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
      @{ var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.ImageThumbnail); var thumbSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64); var base64Modal = Convert.ToBase64String(image.Image); var imgSrcModal = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64Modal);
      var imageId = "pop" + image.YogaSpaceImageId; var imagesourceId = "imagesource" + image.YogaSpaceImageId; }
      <a class="image" id="@imageId" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <img id="@imagesourceId" src="@thumbSrc" data-imagesrc="@imgSrcModal" alt="image not found" width="203" height="136" />
      </a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a>  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your element is a hyperlink I think you'll need to call preventDefault() on the event to prevent the browser event bubbling.

Also, I suggest the use of .on over .click because the former can use less memory.

```js
$('.close').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    $("#sortable").sort();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two divs enclosing a tag with class close. So i guess it should be

`$('.close').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  $("#sortable").sort();
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
      connectWith: "ul",
      dropOnEmpty: false
});
```